# react native asyncStorage with useEffect rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, asyncstorage

I'm trying to get item from local storage but its not rendering with me correctly, which I should refresh the app by making any change in the code and save whenever I log in or logout here is my code

[image]

```
    useEffect(() => {
    const _getUserhData = async () => {
        try {
            let userInfo = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userData');
            if (userInfo) {
                const parsedUserData = JSON.parse(userInfo);
                setUserData(parsedUserData);
                console.log(userData, 'userData');

            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error retrieving data:', error);
        }
    };

    _getUserhData();
},  [userInfo]);
```

Comment: Your variable declare inside the hook, this is the reason the useEffect() doesn’t know it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you have shared there is no `userInfo` declared in scope, e.g. the scope of the React function component body.

From what I can tell of your code you should just remove `userInfo` and use an empty dependency array since there are no external dependencies in the `useEffect` hook callback.

```js
const [userData, setUserData] = React.useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  const getUserData = async () => {
    try {
      const userInfo = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userData');
      setUserData(JSON.parse(userInfo));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error retrieving data:', error);
    }
  };

  getUserData();
},  []);
```

Comment: id do that but then it get renderd only one time

Comment: @OmARHaMeD Are you saying that your component renders only once, that calling `setUserData` doesn't trigger a component rerender with the new value? Please clarify.

Comment: when user opens the screen the data doesnt update from local storage automatically,

Comment: @OmARHaMeD The `useEffect` hook callback is guaranteed to run ***at least*** once when the component mounts, at the end of the initial render cycle. Is it possible that your storage just doesn't have the value you expect already stored in it, so it's just enqueueing a state update to `null` which matches the initial state value?

Answer (score 0):

Use this when user opens the screen

```
useEffect(() => {

    const subscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
       // your user data code
    })

    return () => {
        subscribe;
    }
}, [])

const navigation = useNavigation()
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('userData').then((response) => {
        if (response) {
            const parsedUserData = JSON.parse(response);
            setUserData(parsedUserData);
            console.log(response, 'userData');

        }
    })
},  []);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).